# Updating Tag basis Date column basis condition

Tags: python, dataframe

Existing Dataframe :

```
id             Date                   Tag
01      sep 2021 - 2023               ok
02      feb 2019 - aug 2020           ok
03      07/2022 - 11/2022             ok
04      2013-2017                     ok
```

Conditions that need to be applied : **checking which is the max year in the Date if max year is lesser <= 2020 Tag needs to updated to 'Old' else no change**

Expected Dataframe :

```
id             Date                   Tag
01      sep 2021 - 2023               ok
02      feb 2019 - aug 2020           Old
03      07/2022 - 11/2022             ok
04      2013-2017                     Old
```

i tried approaching it with `df['Dates'].dt.year.max()` but how to apply conditional statement for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`numpy.fromiter`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) :

```
import numpy as np

#make a list of the two years
ser = df["Date"].str.findall("(\d{4})")

#get the maximum year
arr = np.fromiter((max(x) for x in ser), int)

#check if the max year is <= 2020 and make a mapping
df["Tag"] = pd.Series(arr).le(2020).map({False:"Ok", True: "Old"})
```

*NB : If the maximum year is always at the right side of the column `Date`, you can simply use :*

```
df["Tag"] = df["Date"].str.strip().str[-4:].le("2020").map({False:"Ok", True: "Old"})
```

​Output :

```
print(df)

   id                 Date  Tag
0   1      sep 2021 - 2023   Ok
1   2  feb 2019 - aug 2020  Old
2   3    07/2022 - 11/2022   Ok
3   4            2013-2017  Old
```